# Describing Historical Events

Tags: history, tenses

When we describe historical events, like events related to the Roman empires, Persian empires, etc., what is the best way to describe peoples' thought with a connection to the present?

> People **might have thought** the same back in those days, but you know it's not always correct.
>
> People **had thought** the same back in those days, but you know it's not always correct.
>
> People **thought** the same back in those days, but you know it's not always correct.

Comment: Just as a side note, what is "it's" referring to?  The sentence doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: It might be a point previously made in the conversation... And that's not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*People had thought . . .* would not be used in this context because that construction describes an event that occurred before some other event in the past. *People thought . . .* conveys certainty. *People might have thought . . .* suggests doubt.

Comment: Could you give me an example where 'people had thought' might be appropriate?

Comment: @Noah Some people had thought it was the other way until it was shown that the sun revolved around the earth.

Comment: OK, you might have got the first paragraph dead right when you wrote this answer, but I'm not happy with the second. Wouldn't that have been *may have thought*?

Comment: _Might have thought_ = we’re not sure whether they thought or not. _May have thought_ = it was possible at the time that they thought, but we know they didn’t.

Comment: @Barrie: ??? As I use the language, precisely the other way about: *may* can only indicate uncertainty in the present. (I now see that the first half of my comment was ambiguous, but that doesn't change the point.)

Comment: We can say _He may have been killed_, meaning that we don’t know if has died or not. But we can’t say _I may have been killed_ without believing in zombies.