# Storytelling In Simple Present

Tags: grammar

When telling a story in the present tense, what tense should we use for actions that take place before another action in the story, for example:

> The king turns to his wife, who has already had a heart attack, and asks her...[Present Perfect]
>
> The king turns to his wife, who had already had a heart attack, and asks her...[Past Perfect]
>
> The king turns to his wife, who already had a heart attack, and ask her...[Simple Past]
>
> The king turns to his wife, who already has a heart attack, and asks her...[Present Simple]

Comment: You could have waited for your previous question to be answered before posting this. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58109/describing-historical-events

Comment: To see how to do this, take a lesson from the [master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Runyon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tense you use for actions that took place before the action you are currently relating is determined by the usual criteria.

If that prior action has a current relevance, use the present perfect:

- He looks for the money he has lost.

If that prior action happened in finished time, use the past simple:

- He looks for the money he lost the day before.

The reason why the first sentence you quote is the best of the 4 choices is because the word 'already' (in British English at least) generally requires the present perfect tense. We say: "*I've already eaten*", not "*I already ate*".

Comment: Is there any case in which we would use the past perfect?

Comment: @Noah, You can certainly use the past perfect in relating a conditional. Example: "He realises that she would not have died if she *had followed* his advice." As for the past perfect in "The king turns to his wife, who had already had a heart attack, and asks her ... ", I would probably not use it myself, but I don't regard it as an egregious error.

Answer (score 2):

In most circumstances, the first of those would be the normal way of putting it.

Comment: The third of these is also acceptable in American English, but would  be uncommon, I believe, in British English.

Comment: @PeterShor: Perhaps, but it seems to me that the present perfect construction is required to show that the past event, the heart attack, is of current relevance.